# In React Native, why are there alerts when modals are more customizable?

Tags: react-native

I'm trying to create custom alerts using React Native, and found some examples that accomplish this using modals. Why are there modals and alerts if modals are more customizable? Are there pros of alerts over modals? If so, what are they?

For an example, I looked at another Stack Overflow question regarding alerts, and they linked to this: https://github.com/maxs15/react-native-modalbox

Thank you! (New to React and React Native!)

Answer (score 0):

Alerts are much more restricted in what they can do (basically ask the user for a confirmation or a choice among a very limited set of options). But if they fit your need, the advantage is that you can just use them out of the box. Another point is that users are familiar with their design and will quickly understand that you are asking for a confirmation of any sort.

Modals provide you with much more freedom since you can basically render whatever components you want in them. But you need to write them yourself.

So if alerts suit your needs, use them, otherwise you can build your own modal.

Also, unlike in web development, alerts won't stop the execution in React Native, so there is no difference in behavior compared to modals.

Comment: Makes sense, Thank you!